# CORS when both client & server are localhost?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, google-chrome, cors

I am trying to develop a client/server app with AngluarJS & PHP (which is probably AJAX as it just handles HTTP GET and never actually displays a page in a browser).

I use XAMPP Apache for my localhost and develop the client in the [Brackets IDE](http://brackets.io/). Brackets runs a "live preview" on local host port 49883.

[Update] It chooses a new port after each reboot, so if I want to align my Apache with that, then i have manually edit the config after each reboot (ick).

When I try to `$http.get('http://127.0.0.1/my_script.php?action=overview_map&date=2014-04-12&user=abc')`

the debug console shows.

`No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:49833' is therefore not allowed access.`

How can I get around this?

I put this line in my Windows hosts file `127.0.0.1 test_site` and this in my PHP
`header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: test_site'` but I still get `The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'test_site'.`

Perhaps there is some way to get Brackets to start Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` option, so as to have no CORS problems at all?

Or another (free) IDE which handles this?

This is all new to me, but there must be many, many, many others out there developing with client & server (preferably with JS & PHP) on localhost. How do you do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using different port. It is subject to CORS.

Comment: +1 Thanks, @Miraage. so, if I change my Apache to Listen on port 49833 in addition to 80, it should work?

Comment: Most likely, XHR will send OPTIONS request, that should respond header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" or "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: yourhost:49833".